# How to develop cordova apps for Jelly Bean?

Tags: android-4.2-jelly-bean, web-inspector

I've been building a cordova/ionic app and everything was looking great except on Android devices with Jelly Bean. These issues are incredibly difficult to sort out without an inspector. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the best way to develop for Jelly Bean is by using an old version of a webkit browser. I particularly use Safari 5.7.1 but since I'm on OSX I have to use a windows VM to run it.

[I downloaded an old copy of Safari here](http://safari.en.softonic.com/)

Hope this info is helpful to someone else.

Comment: This old copy of Safari helped me tremendously to resolve my UI issues in my ionic app.